# c - how can I print specified count of a char in a line

Tags: c, printf

I want to print a line similar as following:

```
====================================
```

And I need to control the count of the char, and able to specify which char to print.

I don't want to use loop.

Is it possible to do this with a single `printf()` statement?

---

@Update

I ask this because I use printf in this way sometimes:

`printf("%10s\n", "abc");`

So, if printf could do this, then it's possible to do what I ask, I am just not sure ... now I know it can't ...

Ok, I wrote a simple util function to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printRepeatChar(char c, int count) {
    char cs[count+1];
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
        cs[i] = c;
    cs[count] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", cs);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    printRepeatChar('-', 6*4);
}
```

maybe use `memset()` from `string.h` instead of the direct loop makes the code shorter, just as in the answers.

And, thank you all for help.

Comment: scan a character and print it using loop!!

Comment: @vaultah I don't want to use loop, I am wondering is it possible to do this within a single simple statement.

Comment: There isn't a standard function that does the job, nor a format specification in `printf()` that will do it.  Therefore, you'll have to write one for yourself, and the body of that function will be a loop.  `static inline int repeat_char(char c, int count) { for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) if (putchar(c) != c) return EOF; return count; }`.

Comment: @EricWang And writting your own function, possibly using loop & printf() wouldn't work?

Comment: there is no magic in c. everything is reasonable. do you think there will be such a function without you or somebody write there own?

Comment: @FanaticD It would work, I am just wondering does printf() already has this ability to do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void PrintStuff( char to_print, int length ) {

    // adjust buffer size as desired
    char buffer[256];

    // -1 for null terminator
    if( length > sizeof(buffer)-1 ) length = sizeof(buffer)-1; 

    // fill buffer with desired character
    memset( buffer, to_print, length );

    // add null terminator
    buffer[length] = 0;

    // print to output
    puts( buffer );
}

int main() {
    PrintStuff( '=', 11 );
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/RjPr83

---

And to answer the subquestion: no, printf cannot repeat a character as a formatting rule. It can only repeat spaces or 0's when padding.

Comment: Note that you've forced a newline after the output; this reduces the flexibility of your function.  You'd do better with `fputs(buffer, stdout)` which does not add the newline, so the user could generate a single line like `====----!!!!----====` by calling your function, whereas as it stands, that would all appear on 5 lines, not one. Also, it seems a pity to limit the repeat count to 127.  Granted, most of the time that'll be enough, but do you really need to impose the limit?

Comment: Having said that, the OP's own solution outputs a newline at the end, so you're in good company at least.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Your idea is good, I might refactor the function in that way if I need to print a more complex line, but now all I need is to print a header line wrapper, so it's ok.

Comment: Adjusted for those Extra Wide terminals, if this was c++ i would most definitely put an optional argument for adding a newline

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void) {
    char c='=';
    char a[20];
    memset(a,c,(sizeof(a)-1));
    a[19] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Dynamic memory allocation and character scanning can be added to this .